# Выборочное перенаправление

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как сделать перенаправление для станиц типа `.../page/{любое число}` так, чтобы он работал только на числа, а `.../page/{текст}` пропускал?
`RedirectMatch 301 /page/.*` срабатывает на все символы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог такой редирект

```
RedirectMatch 301 /page/[0123456789]+$ http://anotherpage
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^page\/([0-9]*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`[0-9]` - любая цифра
`$` - до конца url. Если просто поставить `[0-9]*` подойдет любой url, тк `*` может означать и 0 вхождений

Comment: Т. е. исходный результат такой: RedirectMatch 301 /page\/(0-9)*$ http://{куда_надо}? У меня не сработал...

Comment: @Tarasovych Переписал через `RewriteRule`; с `RedirectMatch` не знаком